# javascript code to allow only numbers and single dot in text box

Tags: javascript

Javascript code to add only numbers and single dot in price value text box

```
function isNumberandDot(evt){
    var iKeyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (iKeyCode != 46 && iKeyCode > 31 && (iKeyCode < 48 || iKeyCode > 57)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;    
}
```

I am using above code to allow number and comma.

Comment: And where is the question?

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: The question is - I want that only numbers and one dot to be allowed in the text box. The above code is allowing numbers and many dots can be added.

Answer (score 0):

The decimal point has got a key code of `110`

Therefore, just check `iKeyCode` against `110` and you should be fine.

Comment: The requirement is to allow only single dot in check box along with numbers. Even if the keycode is 110 how can we add the validation to allow only one dot? Kindly help

Comment: Well, you already check for `46` and `48` to `57`, which I assume are `,` and the `0-9`. Just add another check for `110`